# IPv4 RegEx in PHP is not matching the IPs with last octet being 3 digit

Tags: php, regex

I have a regex **
**

I am using `preg_match_all` method in PHP to match the Ips.
But it doesn't match the IP if the last octet is 3 digits.
Plz can anyone help me and let me know where I am going wrong.

Code is like:

```
$tnlip_regex = "/(([1-9]?\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])[\.])(([1-9]?\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])[\.])(([1-9]?\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])[\.])(([1-9]?\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5]))/";
preg_match_all($tnlip_regex, $row_data, $tnlip_matches);
```

`$row_data` is the data from where I am finding IPs.
`$tnlip_matches` is the array where I am putting them.

Answer (score 1):

Your regexp looks wrong as follows-

[image]

You need this-

```
^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|(1[0-9]{2}|2[0-5]{2}))\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|(1[0-9]{2}|2[0-5]{2}))\.([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|(1[0-9]{2}|2[0-5]{2}))$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

You can test the validity of any IP address using this rule here : [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/3sGWe9cfwp3fmmX4)

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the alternate order to try 3 digits first:

http://regex101.com/r/nN4qG7

```
((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|([1-9])?[0-9])\.){3}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|1[0-9][0-9]|([1-9])?[0-9])
```

If `([1-9])?[0-9]` comes first, it may match `12` in `123` and ignores the other alternate.

Answer (score 0):

try this find only valid ip

```
  $row_data='10.168.3.344  10.168.3.244 192.168.0.244';
  $tnlip_regex = "#[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+#";
  preg_match_all($tnlip_regex, $row_data, $tnlip_matches);
  foreach($tnlip_matches[0] as $Key=>$Val){
     if(!filter_var($Val, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){//check for valid ip
        unset($tnlip_matches[0][$Key]);
     }
   }
   print_r($tnlip_matches);
```

output

```
 Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [1] => 10.168.3.244
        [2] => 192.168.0.244
    )

)
```